# What's the difference between domain model and conceptual model

Tags: domain-model

According to wikipedia they seem to be the same thing, but they each have different pages.

[Domain Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model)

[Conceptual Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceptual_model_%28computer_science%29)

On the conceptual model page it says these two things:

`A Conceptual model in the field of computer science is also known as a domain model.`

`a conceptual model represents 'concepts' (entities) and relationships between them.`

But on the domain model page it says

`A domain model in problem solving and software engineering is a conceptual model of all the topics related to a specific problem. It describes the various entities, their attributes, roles, and relationships, plus the constraints that govern the problem domain.`

Are they actually the exact same thing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Domain model-Conceptual model has different meanings in different context.

**But in Object Oriented Analysis context they are same**

> A domain model is a visual representation of conceptual classes or
> real-situation objects in a domain  **[MO95, Fowler96]**. **Domain models
> have also been called conceptual models** (the term used in the first
> edition of this book), domain object models, and analysis object
> models.[ page 134]
>
> Source : Applying UML and Patterns - Third Edition -By Craig Larman
>
> **MO95** Martin, J., and Odell, J. 1995. Object-Oriented Methods: A
> Foundation. Englewood Cliffs, NJ.: Prent
>
> **Fowler96** Fowler, M. 1996. Analysis Patterns: Reusable Object Models.*
> Reading, MA.: Addison-Wesley